# Merge sort in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, sorting, clojure, mergesort

I made my own version of merge sort:

```clj
    (defn rsort[a]
      (cond 
        (<= (count a) 1) a
        :else 
          (let [half    (/ (count a) 2) 
                [lh rh] (split-at half a)]
            (loop [res () slh (rsort lh) srh (rsort rh)]
              (cond 
                (empty? slh) (into srh res)
                (empty? srh) (into slh res)
                :else 
                  (if (< (first slh) (first srh))
                    (recur (cons (first slh) res) (rest slh) srh)
                    (recur (cons (first srh) res) slh (rest srh))))))))
```

Any suggestion how improve this code?

Comment: Does this work with lists?  Your usage if `into` makes me think it will only work with vectors.

Comment: Yeah, Its works for list and vectors as well.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested with a couple of input values and for the most part, it seem
fine.  Note however, that the standard `sort` also works with
e.g. `[1 nil]` (with output `[nil 1]`) whereas this code breaks with an
exception during the comparison.

Code looks fine with a few minor issues:

- The name should be `merge-sort`; `rsort` is not meaningful.
- The values `(first slh)` and `(first srh)` are written down twice; the
  compiler might optimise that away, but IMO it would be nicer to have a
  separate `let` for them.
- Emacs' `clojure-mode` indents the `:else` branch differently, dunno
  about that.

Some suggestions:

- Support the same signature as the standard `sort`.
- Add a docstring explaining the function.
- Add tests, possibly with randomised input as well.